# Performancecounter reporting werid CPU usage values

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I have the following code:

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        float Percent = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        Console.WriteLine("Sampling CPU Usage               " + Percent);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Percent = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        Console.WriteLine("Sampling CPU Usage               " + Percent);
        Percent = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        Console.WriteLine("Sampling CPU Usage               " + Percent);
```

and the output I get is :

```
Sampling CPU Usage               0
Sampling CPU Usage               396
Sampling CPU Usage               405
```

Now yes I have have 2 physical cores so I could divide by 2 but on another machine I see the correct percentage. Also the 'rawvalue' appears as 2020334375000

Comment: It is crucial that you wait long enough before calling NextValue() again.  The processor can only ever be turned off or run at full bore.  So all that the counter can do is measure for how many ticks it was off vs running since the last time it was called.  Failure to do so produces weirdo values.  Not in the least because modern processors don't run at a predictable speed anymore.  They have a "turbo boost" feature, intentionally over-clocking the processor as long as the chip temperature stays low enough.  The counter compensates for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather stupidly I had "Process" instead of "Processor" for the first argument, the code should be

```
new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```